# How to find the minimum value greater than 0 in a pandas df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, debugging, minimum

Suppose I got the following `df_percentage_change`:

```
Index End Date                Change
0     2022-06-18 19:59:59.999 0
1     2022-06-18 20:29:59.999 -0.020028
2     2022-06-18 20:59:59.999 1.53509
3     2022-06-18 21:29:59.999 2.30751
```

How can I get the minimum value greater than 0 in the column `Change` (which is `1.53509`) using a single line of code?

I tried the following:

```
df_percentage_change["Change"].apply(lambda x: min(df_percentage_change["Change"]) if df_percentage_change["Change"] > 0)
```

But got:

> **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured it out:

> **In [1]:** `min(filter(lambda x: x > 0, df_percentage_change["Change"]))`
>
> **Out[2]: 1.53509**